# Use GPU and computer resources in pararalell

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

If my GPU runs out of memory while running tensorflow is there any way to use in parallel the computer memory, for example while compiling tensorflow is there any configuration.

I read in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) the section of "Allowing GPU memory growth" but didn't saw anything about share resources.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A couple of ops support it using "swap_memory=True" parameters. Also you can specific ops to use CPU memory by using `with tf.device` annotations

Comment: thanks!, I was running out of memory in my gpu so I set the swap_memory parameter to True in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn and that work